# How to divide two columns in R for bigdata?

Tags: r

I had df contains 2 columns with ratio values, I'd like to divide these columns and put the resultant value into a new column. Some suggestions please.

```
2/120 =  0.01666667, 119/9238 = 0.01288158, A/B = ?

Example
A              B            new
2/120       119/9238        ?
1/120       47/9238
6/120       422/9238
1/120       50/9238
2/120       127/9238
1/120       52/9238
1/120       52/9238
3/120       205/9238
1/120       53/9238
1/120       53/9238
1/120       53/9238
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#Data
mdf <- structure(list(A = c("2/120", "1/120", "6/120", "1/120", "2/120", 
"1/120", "1/120", "3/120", "1/120", "1/120", "1/120"), B = c("119/9238", 
"47/9238", "422/9238", "50/9238", "127/9238", "52/9238", "52/9238", 
"205/9238", "53/9238", "53/9238", "53/9238")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

#Code
mdf$Col1 <- apply(mdf[,'A',drop=F],1,function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
mdf$Col2 <- apply(mdf[,'B',drop=F],1,function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
mdf$Ratio <- mdf$Col1/mdf$Col2

       A        B        Col1        Col2    Ratio
1  2/120 119/9238 0.016666667 0.012881576 1.293838
2  1/120  47/9238 0.008333333 0.005087681 1.637943
3  6/120 422/9238 0.050000000 0.045680883 1.094550
4  1/120  50/9238 0.008333333 0.005412427 1.539667
5  2/120 127/9238 0.016666667 0.013747564 1.212336
6  1/120  52/9238 0.008333333 0.005628924 1.480449
7  1/120  52/9238 0.008333333 0.005628924 1.480449
8  3/120 205/9238 0.025000000 0.022190950 1.126585
9  1/120  53/9238 0.008333333 0.005737173 1.452516
10 1/120  53/9238 0.008333333 0.005737173 1.452516
11 1/120  53/9238 0.008333333 0.005737173 1.452516
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try to first separate one column into two at the position of the "/"

```
df <- Data %>%  
  separate(V1, into=c('a', 'b'), sep="/") %>% 
 separate(V2, into=c('d','e'), sep="/")
```

then chnage the class to "numeric"

`df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)`

and finally create the columns with the divided results:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(ab=a/b, de=d/e)
```

i hope this works :)

Comment: Did you mean to use `%>%` ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I corrected it now

Comment: dff <- dff %>%
   mutate(ab=a/b,de=d/e,abde=ab/de), works perfect @ BeccaLi